# PHP include function not display images or css

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

I am testing a small blog site I created using XAMPP. PHP files work with includes when in parent folder, but I have a folder called "2016" inside the same htdocs folder and in that folder I have "1" "2" "3" "4" etc for the months.

In each of these folders I will put blog posts (php files with html includes), but when I do the includes, only the html is loaded, the images nor the css are not.

Below are the includes I have tried:

```
<?php
$page_title = 'Test Page';



$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/includes/header.html";
include($path);



?>
```

and also tried

```
<?php

include ('/../../includes/sidebar.html');

include ('/../../includes/footer.html');

?>
```

Neither options have worked.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried checking your browser's console for errors when opening the HTML page?

Comment: The page is in php and the includes are html but I haven't experienced any errors, just for some reason the includes aren't showing images or css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using relative path to load your images and css.

Simple solution is to make your relative path to absolute.

You can achieve this like:

1) Use Base Path in html head tag

```
 <base href="http://localhost/yoursite/">
```

Now you can load images and css in relative way as it knows what is the base path after you define it.
Now you can use something like

```
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

With php

```
  $base_url = 'http://localhost/yoursite/';
```

and then

```
<img src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/images/image1.png"/>
```

Comment: But now I have another problem, instead of using  <base href="http://localhost/yoursite/">  I used  <base href="http://localhost/"> 

but now every php file in the htdocs folder that has a back to top button, when I click the button, instead of taking me back to the top of the page it takes me to the home page :/